# AugularJS UI Router has element in dom but display blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an app with Ionic + AngularJS, with a starter app.
It's basically tab view + side menu. **[Playground here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjDOfYgcrlpZuOmGkiLw?p=preview)**
So far I've achieved most of my goals, except for below weird actions:

1. When you click on the item from landing page, it goes to the view, view title changed successfully, but no content displayed. But if you inspect the element the content was there.
2. If you do a refresh on the blank page, it will jump back to landing page, then if you click the items on the landing page, it opens the blank page with content displayed.
3. There are two certain pages that have further questions, it is the blank page mentioned above and the next page when you click an item on the blank page. On these two pages when you do a refresh, it will jump back to landing page, why?
4. Also when I'm on these two pages, the bottom tab doesn't change it's active state, meaning you cannot navigate to home page by clicking home when you are on these two pages.

Piece of code here:

```js
    .state('app.cat', {
      url: '/cat/:catname',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
          controller: 'CatCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.card', {
      url: '/cat/:catname/:cardtitle',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/card.html',
          controller: 'CardCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Looks a lot to ask but I've been stuck here for a while, if you could shed any lights on this that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create factory like this

```
.factory('Cards', function($q) {
    // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

    // Some fake testing data
    var cards = [{
        "categories": [{
            "catid": "1",
            "catname": "Test 1",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-1",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"11","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"img/list-1.jpg"
            }, {
                "id":"12","title": "Cat 1 Cards 2","cover":"img/list-2.jpg"
            }]
        }, {
            "catid": "1",
            "catname": "Test 2",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-2",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"11","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"11"
            }, {
                "id":"12","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"12"
            }]
        }, {
            "catid": "1",
            "catname": "Test 3",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-3",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"11","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"11"
            }, {
                "id":"12","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"12"
            }]
        }, {
            "catid": "1",
            "catname": "Test 4",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-4",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"11","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"11"
            }, {
                "id":"12","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"12"
            }]
        }, {
            "catid": "1",
            "catname": "Test 5",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-5",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"11","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"11"
            }, {
                "id":"12","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"12"
            }]
        }, {
            "catid": "2",
            "catname": "Test 6",
            "catbanner":"//placehold.it/300x100?test-6",
            "cards": [{
                "id":"21","title": "Cat 1 Cards 1","cover":"21"
            }]
        }]
    }];
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var _cat = []
    var _remove =  function(card) {      cards.splice(cards.indexOf(card), 1);    }
    var _getCat =  function(catname) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cards[0].categories.length; i++) {
            if (cards[0].categories[i].catname === catname) {
                array.push(cards[0].categories[i]);            
            }
        }
        angular.copy(array, _cat);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var _getCard = function(catname, cardtitle) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cards[0].categories.length; i++) {
            if (cards[0].categories[i].catname === catname) {
                for (var k = 0; i < cards[0].categories[i].cards.length; k++) {
                    if (cards[0].categories[i].cards[k].title === cardtitle) {
                        array.push(cards[0].categories[i].cards[k]);
                    }}
                array.push(cards[0].categories[i]);
            }
        }
        angular.copy(array, _cards);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        all: function() {   return cards;   },
        remove:_remove,
        getCat:_getCat,
        getCard:_getCard,
        cat: _cat,
        cards: _cards
    };
});
```

and call methode who return promise like below

```
 Cards.getCat($stateParams.catname).then(function () { $scope.cat = Cards.cat}, function () { alert("Error") });
```

Comment: Thank you Jasmin, your code looks neat, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: No worries, thank you any way. I may just need a beer.